# dynamic data and dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have 3 dc.js charts on my page. I would like to make the data it consumes as dynamic as concurrent users might range from 5 to 15 users. If I use .CSV and .JSON, the physical file needs to be created on server and concurrency would be an issue. Is there a way to pass in-memory data to d3.js for rendering the charts? Any example/help is appreciated.

Thanks
BV

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic data? i.e. does it change somehow on the server side and you would like the user to see the updated data as it changes? And why would concurrency be an issue here..?

Comment: Agree with @adarren, also crossfilter simply takes an array of data, so however you get your data in JavaScript, just pass the array into crossfilter - you don't need to use CSV or JSON. However, I suspect that you really need to ask a question about how to structure your server and you will probably still end up generating CSV or JSON on the fly and sending it down to multiple clients.

Comment: i have implemented a rest service that returns json data. The url for this service has been passed on to d3.json function for processing and displaying the chart. dynamic data is the data filtered and served as json based on user selection in another screen. each used can use the search/filter screen to filter the data and view it on the d3 charts. since having a specific physical csv file for each user is data intensive, we decided to serve json on the fly to d3.